# Error: unable to insert an object of type list cell in the selected location

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I want to copy and paste the highlighted cell (which is an expression it's total of the amount) just below it and i am getting error. unable to insert an object of type list cell in the selected location.

From toolbox i am also trying to insert block but it's not going in that particular cell, but getting pasted sidewise.

[image]

[image]
I have Cognos 11

Comment: My answer is a guess.  Please provide screen captures that show more context.  Better, reproduce the problem using the GO Sales (query) package and post the report spec as part of your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to copy a list cell into a table cell.  I doubt that's what you really want to do.  You could try copying the text item from one cell to the other by first unlocking the page, but that shouldn't work either because a table cell is not a data container.

To add data to a table cell, first add a singleton to the table cell.  Then add the data item to the singleton.

When you insert a block into a list, Cognos will create a column wherein each cell in the column body contains the block.  This makes perfect sense in the context of a list.

Adding a block to a table cell should work just fine.  You must be dropping the block in the wrong location.  Try dropping it on the table cell rather than on the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't unlock the page that's why i was facing issue.